# Why no one else used Conqueror's Haki?

Tags: one-piece

In Marineford, there were other people than Luffy who had Conqueror's Haki (Whitebeard, Hancock, etc.). Why didn't they use it when Ace was about to get beheaded? Because if Luffy did not use it unknowingly, Ace would have died sooner. Or was it the case that no one had Conqueror's Haki as powerful as Luffy's which could act at a large distance?

Comment: I follow what Oshino said. They all didn't use Haki due to circumstances. Whitebeard was having heart problems at the time, Doffy couldn't care less, Boa was taking care of Pacifista, Ace himself had accepted his death and Garp wasn't in a position to intervene.

Comment: I don't understand why is this question on hold, there's a reason why nobody use haki to safe Ace. Like Peter comment and my answer. It answer this question without any opinion but with fact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are other people who could use Conqueror's Haki at that moment. On rescue team, they're Shirohige and Hancock. But only Shirohige knows about Ace's situation and Hancock was fighting somewhere else. However, Shirohige wasn't in good condition to use Conqueror's Haki. He was sick and badly injured by some attack by Marine just before Ace's execution order.

[image]

Some other source said Conqueror's Haki needs heart to use it and Shirohige couldn't use Conqueror's Haki because his heart was injured. But at this point, I can't find any canon source to endorse the statement.

Comment: They weren't talking about the physical heart but his concentration did break right when he was about to use it due to his health condition.

Comment: While waiting for the new chapter to come out, I was rewatching the marineford arc and Whitebeard actually confirmed your post. He said "Just now, you managed to prevent Ace's execution in my place...", confirming that he was about to use Haki, but couldn't due to his heart and Luffy did it instead.

Comment: My comment was in reference to "haki needs heart".  It was just his heart failing at an in opportune time.

Comment: After rereading the Amazon Lily Arc, it seems that Boa Hancock, would not have been able to use Conqueror's haki, even if she knew about the execution. In chapter 519 she said that she hadn't even mastered it yet.

Answer (score 0):

whitebeard not use Conqueror's Haki  because it effect on all peoples without powerful will so his man also effected with that. It's king personality i think

Comment: That is a side effect that apply only to inexperienced users. Once you master Conquer's Haki you can select whom you want to be your target, as Rayleigh and Luffy (after the timeskip) do. I find hard to believe Whitebeard an inexperienced user...

Answer (score -2):

It's simple, you need extensive training to use Conqueror's Haki. Only certain people like Luffy, Rayleigh, Shanks, and Doffy trained their Conqueror's Haki.